# 415 unsupported media type + spring

Tags: java, spring, jackson

**The problem:** 
I'm trying to send a request as a `POST` with to parameters: `{id: 20, roleName: "ADMIN"}` and getting this error (415 unsupported media type).

**Framework:**
Spring 4.1.1

In my `@Controller` in server side, I have the following:

```
@RequestMapping("/role/add.action")
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String,Object> addrole(@RequestBody Role role, 
            HttpServletRequest request,
            Authentication authentication,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
    //Code goes here..
}
```

This --> `@RequestBody Role role` works fine for any other type of object but, for `Role` I get this issue.

My `Role` class is:

```
@Entity
public class Role implements Serializable{


    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String roleName;

    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "role", targetEntity = Users.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonManagedReference(value="role")
    private List<Users> users = new LinkedList<Users>();

    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="role_features",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="roleId"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="featureId"))
    @OrderBy(clause="featureId")
    private Set<SystemFeature> features = new HashSet<SystemFeature>();

    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="role_menu",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="roleId"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="menuId"))
    @OrderBy(clause="menuId")
    private Set<Menu> menus = new HashSet<Menu>();

    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="role_services_stations",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="roleId"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="stationId"))
    @OrderBy(clause="stationId")
    private Set<ServiceStation> stations = new HashSet<ServiceStation>();

    //Constructors, getters and setters...

}
```

This class has `java.util.Set` attributes, and I think that this may causing the problem.

I'm sending just two properties: id and roleName. The cast should work, right?

PS: I've set a Jackson `message-converter` bean already, but didn't work.

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="objectMapper">
                    <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper">
                        <property name="serializationInclusion">
                            <value type="com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include">NON_NULL</value>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Someone could help me? xD

Comment: Have you tried with `{"id": 20, "roleName": "ADMIN"}`? (Double-quotes in property names). Also try setting `Content-Type` header to `application/json`.

Comment: What if you change to `@RequestMapping(value="/role/add.action", consumes = "application/json")`

Comment: @orid the payload was sent correctly and the Content-Type is 'Content-Type:application/json' on developer tools. =/

Comment: @Magnamag I made the change you said but didn't work also..

Comment: Ok, is your controller returning `null` or an empty value?

Comment: @Magnamag My controller returns a Map<String,Object>, but when debbuging it doesn't even get inside it..<br>
<br>
Here is the code:<br>
`@RequestMapping("/role/add.action")
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String,Object> addrole(@RequestBody Role role, 
            HttpServletRequest request,
            Authentication authentication,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
  try{
   roleService.add(role);
  }catch(Exception e){
   result.put("message",e.getMessage());
  }
  
  return result;
}`

Comment: The Spring error message is misleading. Check this question for a debug trick: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151017/spring-mvc-responsebody-415-unsupported-media-type?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151017/spring-mvc-responsebody-415-unsupported-media-type?rq=1) It might lead you in the right direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My problem was basically on `@JsonManagedReference`  annotation.

What I did:

1) I changed my payload to a `Map`:

```
public Map<String,Object> addRole(@RequestBody Map payload, 
            HttpServletRequest request,
            Authentication authentication,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
...
}
```

2) Then I tried to cast it with Jackson's ObjectMapper (`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

Role role = mapper.convertValue(payload, Role.class);
```

Then the debugger threw me an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not handle managed/back reference 'parent': no back reference property found from type [collection type; class java.util.Set, contains [simple type, class br.com.ttrans.samapp.model.Menu]]
```

This exception helped find the problem, that (in my case) was the annotation `@JsonManagedReference`. From [docs](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonManagedReference.html):

> Annotation used to indicate that annotated property is part of two-way linkage between fields; and that its role is "parent" (or "forward") link. Value type (class) of property must have a single compatible property annotated with JsonBackReference. Linkage is handled such that the property annotated with this annotation is handled normally (serialized normally, no special handling for deserialization); it is the matching back reference that requires special handling

This is used for **two-way linkage** and my payload was coming **one-way**. So..

3) ...I removed `@JsonManagedReference`'s annotations and kept only `@JsonBackReference` in all nested classes;

Then the debbuger threw me another exception, but this time was:  `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized field ...` so putting `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` on all classes solved my problem.

So after all that I could receive the payload already parsed as `Role`:

```
@RequestMapping("/role/add.action")
@ResponseBody
public Map<String,Object> addRole(@RequestBody Role role, 
            HttpServletRequest request,
            Authentication authentication,
            HttpServletResponse response) {

            ...
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I had almost the same problem, a field with `@JsonBackReference` causing the error. I replaced it with `@JsonIgnore` and it solved the problem. Thanks for the explaination!

Answer (score 1):

dont use both `@JsonBackReference` and `@JsonManagedReference`. remove only`@JsonManagedReference` annotation. it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly due to ManyToMany associations (like features,menus etc).
Modify such that it breaks the json chain, may be adding @JsonIgnore at suitable places will solve it.

Comment: Hi Charybr, I did that also but didn't work... I found this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894955/spring-jsonignore-not-working as the solution this guy changed from fasterxml to codehaus but didn't worked also =//

Comment: I would suggest start with putting JsonIgnore annotation for all OneToMany, ManyToMany associations. Then remove @JsonIgnore for one association at a time. By this way you will be able to pin point which association is causing this.